# Windows AWS Bootstrap with files from S3 using CloudFormation

Tags: windows, bootstrapping, aws-cloudformation

Using AWS CloudFormation, I have two stacks (lets call them Stack A and Stack B), both use cfn-init on startup in the AWS published Windows AMI (CloudFormation tools preinstalled).

In both stacks, the cfn-init script downloads a bunch of files from my S3 bucket. The S3 bucket is created prior to the stack and the files in the bucket are private. A policy is applied to the S3 bucket during the stack creation - "The IAM user created in this stack should be able to Get Objects from the S3 bucket."

When I create both these stacks, Stack A downloads all files without any problems and thus my application doesn't have any issues.

But Stack B, only downloads "few files", and by few files I mean in lexicographical order sometimes one, sometimes the first two or sometimes the first three files only, where its suppose to download 14 different files.

This is blocking further development.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got your dependencies set correctly.  I've seen examples where there is a delay in the propagation of security to S3.  But if you set the dependency of the two instances as requiring the application of the security and user, it should go away.

Comment: Its been a while, but as far as I can remember, I think what I ended up doing was zip the file and unzip it after fetching from S3.